# User Agent to Browser Version

Tags: browser, user-agent

I'm trying to run a report of browser usage from our web application, but only have the full user agent.  Does anyone know of a good way to get the browsers name and version via SQL or C#?

Answer (score 0):

Using `C#`, you may try `HttpBrowserCapabilities`, for example:

```
HttpBrowserCapabilities bc = Request.Browser;
```

Now, `bc.Browser` will give you the name and `bc.Version` will give you the version. Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and you may also check [HttpRequest.UserAgent Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).